# ngStyle not updating the view properly when the condition change

Tags: angular

I've this simple code:

```
keyDown = false;

  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.keyDown = true;
  }

  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.keyDown = false;
  }
```

It simply set `keyDown` to true or false if the user has at least one key pressed on the keyboard. It's binded to this html:

```
    <div class="button"
    [ngStyle]="{'background-color': keyDown ? 'red' : 'trasparent' }">&nbsp;</div>

    <hr>

    Is background filled? {{keyDown}}

.button{
  width:150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid;
}
```

**The problem** is that the first time I press a key, the background change to red, but if I release the key, invoking the `onKeyUp` function, I can see the changes reflected here -> `Is background filled? {{keyDown}}` but the `background` of the div keep being red.

I've tried using `changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();` in the `onKeyUp` function but it doesn't work.

Here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iabrxs

Any toughts?

*EDIT*: Don't propose the use of `ngClass` since in the main app the buttons are generated dinamically following a certain configuration that, also, defines its custom colors.

Comment: typo `transparent`

Comment: Where did the answer go? It was right. Removing `trasparent` solved this anyway. But why?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi : you have written `trasparent` instead of `transparent`. You don't need to remove it. Correct the typo (or remove it ^^)

Comment: Oh my god. I feel so idiot.